# Технология XFORMS в PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет. Интересует данная технология.

Как она сейчас востребована и есть ли будущее у нее?

Какая поддержка браузеров?

Answer (score 1):

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XForms

[Google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=xforms&aq=0&oq=xforms&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

В википедии написано что имеется поддержка у FF. Родной поддержки у остальных браузеров как я понимаю нет. Остальная информация по технологии во второй ссылке.

Comment: спасибо за внимание к вопросу